# Wordpress CPT & Custom Taxonomy Archives

Tags: wordpress

I have 4 custom post types set up. Articles, Media Posts, Seminars & Workouts. I want each to have their own set of categories they can be categorized by. I need each of their categories to be accessible via URL and list the posts of that type that are in said category.

Is this possible? I'm on 3.1 with a modified twentyten theme. I wouldn't ask, but we're going on 2 days of trying here.

Answer (score 1):

You can categorize your Custom Post Types using Custom Taxonomies : http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Custom Taxonomies can be shared (or not) between different post types...